# Using Transaction with runnable

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I have a `@Singleton` ejb class with this method. Transaction is committed at the end of the method body but I have some other stuff in the myRunnable thread that I want it to be included in the current transaction. Is there any way to do that?

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        // do some other stuff
        managedExecutorService.execute(myRunnable);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error when initializing...", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted to compensate a strange downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Your "myRunnable thread" can not be included in your running transaction.

You must not use a java executor service (EJB Spec 16.2.2) or manage threads directly:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. ... These functions are reserved for the EJB container. Allowing the enterprise bean to manage threads would decrease the container’s ability to properly manage the runtime environment.

You have to use the [managed executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) introduced with Java EE 7.

Regarding transactions, the documentation says:

> Tasks are run in managed threads provided by the Java™ EE Product Provider and are run within the application component context that submitted the task. All tasks run without an explicit transaction (they do not enlist in the application component's transaction). If a transaction is required, use a UserTransaction instance. A UserTransaction instance is available in JNDI using the name: "java:comp/UserTransaction" or by requesting an injection of a UserTransaction object using the Resource annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no way to share transaction context between 2 threads.

You can not transfer transaction context to the asynchronous EJB call for the same reason.

You should rather think of transaction as something which is always thread-bound.

Answer (score 0):

you can create 1 method that call 2 other methods with TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY

```
public void yourMethod(){
    yourMethod1();
    yourMethod2();
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
private void yourMethod1(){
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
private void yourMethod2(){
}
```

TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY will use a transaction from the caller

Comment: What 2 methods? I'm not talking about 2 methods but 2 threads instead.

Comment: The annotation TransactionAttribute within EJBs is for business methods only. Your example methods are private, so no businnes methods at all. And even with public access, a direct call of this method from within the class will not result in a business call on the EJB. I is only a method delegate within the java class running within the managed context of the calling method.